# Sampling from two Gaussian distributions with different probability in Python

Tags: python, probability, gaussian

I am trying to generate 100 samples from 2 different Gaussian distributions, such that G1 occurs with probability 0.7 and G2 occurs with 0.3. I have the following code snippet:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np

x = [norm.rvs(0, 1, size=5), norm.rvs(10, 1, 5)]
draw = np.random.choice([0, 1], 100, p=[0.7, 0.3])
y = [x[i].rvs() for i in draw]
z = np.array(y)
```

When I compile this, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rvs'
```

Is there something I am missing?  Or, is there a fundamental flaw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
x = [norm.rvs(0, 1, size=5), norm.rvs(10, 1, 5)]
```

you are creating two arrays of random values. So in this line

```
[x[i].rvs() for i in draw]
```

you can't use those to create more random values (`.rvs`), since you have numpy arrays:

```
norm.rvs(0, 1, size=5)

# Out: array([-1.61758314,  1.19288111, -0.55599284, -0.17926848, -0.78759   ])
```

---

You want to create a list of normal distribution objects, which you then use to draw random values from:

```
x = [norm(0, 1), norm(10, 1)]
draw = np.random.choice([0, 1], 100, p=[0.7, 0.3])
y = [x[i].rvs() for i in draw]
```

Comment: Thank you!  Apologies, I had to mention this beforehand:  I want the draw-size from each distribution to be 5.  That is, I want 100 samples where each sample belongs to either G1 or G2 and is of size 5.  That's where I am confused.

Comment: My bad!  I got it!  Thank you - I have accepted your answer.

Comment: @Nanda Well, then you could do `[x[i].rvs(5) for i in draw]` to get a 5 x 100 numpy array.

Comment: Yes, I realized that.  In a hurry, I missed supplying 5 to rvs().  Thank you for your time.